# how to resolve following enum related error?

Tags: c++, enums

In abc.h file i have:

```
class a
{
public:
    enum RTDFmodes { 
        verbose,
        NONE,
    };
    class b
    {
        friend class a;
    public:
        RTDFmodes _verbose_mode;
        b(RTDFmodes verbose)
        {
            _verbose_mode=verbose;
        }
    };
};
```

and in abc.cpp i have :

```
int main()
{
    a::RTDFmodes verbose;
    a::b x(verbose);
    return 0;
}
```

when i am running error coming as "verbose is being used without being initialized".
kindly help out how to remove this error.

Comment: Please tag the question with the language you are using and format your code properly. You expect others to read and understand your code so it's more than courtesy to ensure that they are able to do so.

Comment: `verbose` is a local variable of type `a::RTDFmodes`. You never initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

You realize you're using the term `verbose` in three different places, right? The enum value `verbose` is named the same as your b function's argument, as well as your instance of a::RTDFmodes in main():

```
enum RTDFmodes { 
        verbose,  // constant enum value
```

and

```
b(RTDFmodes verbose) // local variable in b() named verbose
```

and

```
a::RTDFmodes verbose;  // local variable in main() named verbose
```

If you want verbose to name the enum value, then you need to change the other two:

```
b(RTDFmodes mode) // the argument is now named mode and can contain the value 'verbose'

a::RTDFmodes mode = a::RTDFmodes::verbose;  // mode contains the value 'verbose'
```

You also have a comma after `NONE` but nothing following it:

```
enum RTDFmodes { 
        verbose,
        NONE,  // Right here
    };
```

Regarding your specific error, the `verbose` you declared in main is never initialized before you pass it to b's constructor, which assigns its data member to it.

For the future, I'd suggest first switching to C++11 strongly-typed enums and then reading up on what enums are and how to use them, as you seem rather confused.